# In what scenarios does merging commits from A to B also bring changes from B to A?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, branching-and-merging

Suppose, I have two branches `C` and `A`, where `A` was made with `C` as base.

Given some time, `C` and `A` will be having different commits based on the features implemented and bugs fixed in both.

Now, suppose I just needed the commits of `C` in `A`. For this I did:

- Made a new branch `B` with `C` as the base branch.
- Created a pull request with `A` as base and compared it with `B`.
- Now I see commits and changes from `C` which were not there in `A` and so I happily merged the PR after some approvals.

After the PR is merged, I see `A` has all the changes of `C` but **wait, `C` has all the changes of `A` as well.**
I just wanted to know in what all scenarios can this happen and well, how I can avoid it?

If this was not the right way to bring changes from `C` to `A`, please let me know the right way of doing it.

Comment: When the PR was merged, _how_ was it merged?

Comment: PR was merged using the Github website. Creation of branch as well as all other stuff took place in the website as well. Sorry, but I didn't understand the 'when' part of your question.

Comment: _"PR was merged using the Github website"_ - sure I get this, but how was it merged? Was it a rebase, merge commit, or something else?

Comment: It was a merge commit.

Comment: If you made a PR of `A` against `B`, since `B` contains `C`'s commits, when the PR is completed `A` will also contain them.

Comment: Yes, that was intended and I needed the commits of `C` in `A`. But eventhough it happened as intended, after completing the PR, I noticed `C` also has the commits of `A`, which is the issue here.

Comment: I suggest you look at the commit tree to understand why. Remember, branches are only a label which point to _one commit_, and they move.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and your time, I will try looking at the commit tree and see what might have gone wrong.

Comment: It's not a matter of something going wrong. You probably need to learn a bit more about how git works, what branches are, how commits link to each other, and how merging works.

Comment: Yes, definitely, there is a lot to learn here and understanding this incident will help me understand git more.

Comment: @JishnuRaj Maybe you accidentially based B on A (or another branch) instead of C?

Comment: @Jay I can assure you that B was made out of C and I also checked if that was the case afterwards. Moreover if B was based out of A, then it should just show me, there are no changes right? Regardless, there are no branches other than A, B and C in this scenario. Thanks for looking into my dilemma.